# Searching for a high side switch with integrated current sensing

Tags: switches

I am building a high side switch circuit for an automotive application and I need to be able to read the current through the switch. The circuit is powered with a 24V battery and the expected load current is between 2A and 6A (I want to use the same circuit for multiple switches). I think my options are:

1. A p-MOSFET as a switch and an external current sensor
2. A high side switch with integrated current sense.

I wanted to choose the second option because I've been seeing that those usually include multiple protection circuits, and I found the Infineon Profet series which has a lot of models. However, in there is none that meet my requirement in the Profet 24V nor Classic Profet 24V sections. In the 12V section, the [BTS50080](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_BTS50080_1TMA_DS_v01_00_EN-1696432.pdf)  would be almost perfect if it weren't for the fact that it can't measure current at 24V (page 4). I've been searching in other manufacturers but I can't find other model. Are there any other or should I stick with the first option?

Answer (score 2):

On a quick search on the TI [High-side switches](https://www.ti.com/power-management/power-switches/high-side-switches/products.html#1685=6%3B10&105max=28%3B80&) which is filtered on:

- Operating voltage >= 24 V
- Current >= 6 A

There is:

1. [TPS281C30](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS281C30) : 60-V tolerant, 30-mΩ 6-A single-channel high-side switch
2. [TPS27SA08](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS27SA08) : 36-V, 8-mΩ, 10-A, 1-ch, Industrial high-side switch with current sense

The current sense in both of these is via an analog sense `SNS` pin. I.e. you will need an external ADC.